# Firefox and IE not rendering SVG

Tags: firefox, svg

I have a set of SVG images, which are rendered perfectly in Chrome and Opera, but fail to display in FF and IE11 and Edge. Here is one such SVG source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="16px" height="17px" viewBox="0 0 16 17" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Generator: Sketch 49 (51002) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
    <title>bin</title>
    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
    <defs></defs>
    <g id="add-to-cart" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M1.77777778,4.44355556 L1.77777778,15.1102222 C1.77777778,16.0897778 2.57511111,16.888 3.55555556,16.888 L12.4444444,16.888 C13.4248889,16.888 14.2222222,16.0897778 14.2222222,15.1102222 L14.2222222,4.44355556 L1.77777778,4.44355556 Z M7.11111111,13.3333333 L5.33333333,13.3333333 L5.33333333,8 L7.11111111,8 L7.11111111,13.3333333 Z M10.6666667,13.3333333 L8.88888889,13.3333333 L8.88888889,8 L10.6666667,8 L10.6666667,13.3333333 Z M10.6666667,1.77688889 L16,1.77688889 L16,3.55466667 L0,3.55466667 L0,1.77688889 L5.33333333,1.77688889 L5.33333333,0 L10.6666667,0 L10.6666667,1.77688889 Z" id="bin" fill="#00cc66" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The SVG is displayed in HTML like so:

```
<div id="tools">
    <div id="clearbutton" class="button" title="Clear Drawings">
        <svg>
            <image href="image/bin.svg" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 8px 6px 6px 6px;
}

svg image {
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried changing and disabling the explicit width/height properties in CSS, but to no avail. The svg tag is getting resized to any large size, however the image tag stays 0 x 0.

In Chrome and Opera the image is displayed correctly. In the other browsers I can see the size is set to 0 x 0. When I open the image separately in FF, it is displayed fine. In FF network tab, I can see the image in the "response" field, it also says "Size: 16 x 17" in the "response" field. Same in Edge. In IE11, the "response" field shows the image, but says "Size: 0 x 0".

I did notice that IE is complaining I should use explicit closing tag for the "image" tag. Firefox automatically adds these:

```
<image href="image/bin.svg"></image>
```

However even if I add the closing tags, it still doesn't work.

I think there is something wrong with this SVG, or the way I am displaying it. Unfortunately I cannot give you a public link for the site, it is currently under development, and will only be available to registered users later.

Comment: No attributes on the image element, CSS properties don't count for IE/Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem :) After adding width="16px" and height="100%" to HTML, it works.